# System memory 259522560 must be atleast 4.718592E8

Tags: apache-spark

While running a sample spark program from eclipse i am getting below error.

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at 
least 4.718592E8. Please use a larger heap size.
```

I am not creating a jar file. I am trying to run from the eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I specified spark.testing.memory to 2147480000 and it works..

Comment: How did you make the change ?

Comment: final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Word Count Demo")
    .setMaster("local[*]")
    .set("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000");